# String concatenation in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code, I want to do a conditional concatenation, my issue is that at the end of the `for` loop I have all variables starting with `\n`. To remove it I need to strip out each variable. I think there should be some batter way to handle this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
foo = bar = remaining = ''
for i in ['foo', 'foo', 'hello', 'foo', 'tr', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'el']:
    if 'foo' in i:
        foo += '\n%s' % i
    elif 'bar' in i:
        bar += '\n%s' % i
    else:
        remaining += '\n%s' % i
foo = foo.strip()
bar = bar.strip()
remaining = remaining.strip()
```

Comment: Why would you have difficulty removing the ```\n```?  Your own code is what places it in the output variables.  There are a couple of ways you could tidy up that string concatenation to skip the newlines.

Comment: strip() only is not enough use the join method

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt i would like to know some some batter approch to handle this, my code is fully funtional but i think i have done an extra code to handle this satutation

Answer (score 6):

Instead of building strings, build lists and `'\n'.join` then when you finish:

```
foos = []
bars = []
remaining = []
for i in ['foo', 'foo', 'hello', 'foo', 'tr', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'el']:
    if 'foo' in i:
        foos.append(i)
    elif 'bar' in i:
        bars.append(i)
    else:
        remaining.append(i)

foo = '\n'.join(foos)
bar = '\n'.join(bars)
remaining = '\n'.join(remaining)
```

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: Simultaneity is subjective. But yes, I'll admit this was low hanging fruit, and I should have got it right first time

Comment: Hooray join(); much, much more efficient than successive concatenations

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = ''
bar = ''
remaining = ''

_list = ['foo', 'foo', 'hello', 'foo', 'tr', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'el']

for outer in xrange(len(_list)):
    for i, e in enumerate(_list):

        foo += '\n%s' % _list.pop(i) if 'foo' in e else ''
        bar += '\n%s' % _list.pop(i) if 'bar' in e else ''
```